# Load file and play audio on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have have code that allows me to input an mp3 file, and output the audio and display a visual representation of the music. (Loading the file is done manually through an input type="file")

I no longer want to load a file from my computer, but instead automatically play the music on page load. The file is called song.mp3.

I not sure how to adjust my code to allow for the automatic play (I would like the visual representation to also work on load).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
  var file = document.getElementById("thefile");
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  
  file.onchange = function() {
    var files = this.files;
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    src.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    analyser.fftSize = 256;

    var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    console.log(bufferLength);

    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
    var barHeight;
    var x = 0;

    function renderFrame() {
      requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);

      x = 0;

      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

      ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

      for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i];
        
        var r = barHeight + (25 * (i/bufferLength));
        var g = 250 * (i/bufferLength);
        var b = 50;

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + 0 + "," + 0 + "," + 0 + ")";
        ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

        x += barWidth + 1;
      }
    }

    audio.play();
    renderFrame();
  };
};
```

```css
#thefile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

audio {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS Audio Visualizer</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  <div id="content">
  <input type="file" id="thefile" accept="audio/*" />
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
</div>
  
  

    <script  src="./script.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to load and play audio file after you got audio tag from document.

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL("song.mp3");
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

Because Chrome don't allow autoplay audio onload until user has an interactive with the webpage. So you need to add an hidden autoplay `iframe` with silence sound.

```
<iframe src="silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

You can get silence sound file from here https://github.com/anars/blank-audio/blob/master/250-milliseconds-of-silence.mp3

Your js

```
window.onload = function() {
    function renderVisual() {
        var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        src.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(context.destination);

        analyser.fftSize = 256;

        var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
        console.log(bufferLength);

        var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

        var WIDTH = canvas.width;
        var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

        var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
        var barHeight;
        var x = 0;

        function renderFrame() {
            requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);

            x = 0;

            analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

            ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
                barHeight = dataArray[i];

                var r = barHeight + (25 * (i/bufferLength));
                var g = 250 * (i/bufferLength);
                var b = 50;

                ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + 0 + "," + 0 + "," + 0 + ")";
                ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

                x += barWidth + 1;
            }
        }

        renderFrame();
    }

    var context = new AudioContext();
    var file = document.getElementById("thefile");
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.src = "song.mp3";
    audio.load();
    var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    audio.play();
    renderVisual();

    file.onchange = function() {
      var files = this.files;
      audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
      audio.load();
      audio.play();
      renderVisual();
    };
  };
```

Your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS Audio Visualizer</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <div id="content">
  <input type="file" id="thefile" accept="audio/*" />
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
  <iframe src="silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="silence_audio" style="display:none"></iframe>
</div>



    <script  src="./script.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

**Note**: This will get error on Chrome if you open file directly on your local because of `CORS`. You need to host your website to a server (Nginx or Apache).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to play mp3 on page load

You just need to add control and autoplay attributes on the audio tag and then you can play autoplay music

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls autoplay>
  <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Note: It will not work in local you need to host your file on the server

Reference Link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_autoplay