# I've been trying to put sound on my website using jQuery but no change whatsoever

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, audio

I am stuck making a Simon game, which I got inspiration from a Angela Yu's Full-Stack Web Development course on Udemy (Lesson 168). I was trying to add sound to the buttons using jQuery but I find it quite confusing.

I tried declaring a variable called `audio` and assigned to it: `new Audio("./sounds/" + randomChosenColor + ".mp3")` which is the location of the sound, and `randomChosenColor` is a variable which chooses a random color using an array and `Math.random()`.

```js
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);

  $("#" + randomChosenColor).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  var audio = new Audio("./sounds/" + randomChosenColor + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
}

nextSequence();
```

```html
<h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div lass="row">
    <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green"></div>
    <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow"></div>
    <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I assume the problem is that the sound isn't being played...? If so, check the console for errors to make sure that the path to the sound file is correct, and also that the file has loaded before you play it, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57138606/519413